# Is it possible to expand typedef with forced compiler error?

Tags: c++, typedef, incomplete-type

I have been using method shown below to force compiler to yell at me a variable type:

```
template <class T>
struct show_type;
```

Using it with desired variable so compiler errors an incomplete struct type:

```
typedef int32_t s32;
s32 a;
show_type<decltype(a)>();
```

So GCC 5.3.0 produces error:

> invalid use of incomplete type '`struct show_type<int>`'

And MSVC 2015:

> '`show_type<s32>`': no appropriate default constructor available

Now I wonder if there is a way to force an error to show full hierarchy of `typedef`s (that is, `s32 -> int32_t -> int`), or at least newest `typedef` and first original type? I don't mind dirty or evil tricks.

Comment: `typedefs` are simple aliases, not types on their own. You are probably baring up the wrong tree. Provide a [MCVE] with the context please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's true for post-Phase 4 compilation logic, but in Phase 4 there is no syntax checking, so it maybe, there is a chance, it's not impossible or something? Dunno really, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Full hierarchy of *what* `typedef`s? In what context? First original type of *what*? It's unclear to me what you're actually asking for.

Comment: @Barry In given example, it would be `int -> int32_t -> s32`, or `int -> s32` for simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I wonder if there is a way to force an error to show full hierarchy of typedefs (that is, `s32 -> int32_t -> int`), or at least newest typedef and first original type?

There is no such hierarchy. `s32` *is* `int32_t` *is* `int`. There is no way to differentiate those three types, since they aren't actually three different types. Two of those are just aliases.

---

What you're really looking for is static reflection, or [P0194](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0194r0.pdf). That would allow you to do something like:

```
using meta_s32   = reflexpr(s32);
using meta_int32 = meta::get_aliased_t<meta_s32>;
using meta_int   = meta::get_aliased_t<meta_int32>;
std::cout << meta::get_name_v<meta_s32> << ", "
          << meta::get_name_v<meta_int32> << ", "
          << meta::get_name_v<meta_int> << '\n';
```

You could produce the reflection hierarchy by repeatedly going up with `get_aliased_t` and stopping when `is_alias_v` yields `false_type`.

Comment: +1, didn't even known that such thing was even considered to be implemented, but in my opinion it's extremely useful with strong `typedef`ed projects

Comment: @BlackMoses Well, it's just a proposal put forward by a working group. It's unclear when/if it will become part of the C++ standard.